# Shell scripting to display /etc/group

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to write a shell script that displays the system’s users and groups from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` - for each user I want to display the username, UID and all groups the user is a member of.

I tried the following:

```
cat /etc/passwd /etc/group
```

but the output was all over the place. Can someone help me to write this script.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The `id` command can do exactly that:

```
$ id foobar
uid=1000(foobar) gid=1000(foobar) groups=1000(foobar),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom)
```

replace `foobar` with your desired username.

Check `man id` to get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

To get all groups for all entries in `/etc/passwd`

```
for user in $(getent passwd| cut -d: -f1); do groups $user; done
```

#### explanation

- `getent passwd`: lists all lines in `/etc/passwd` in the usual format

  ```
  guest-ZlneMD:x:119:130:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-ZlneMD:/bin/bash
  ```
- `cut -d: -f1`: removes all but the first field (fields are separated by `:`)
  the result is a list of all account names, sorted by UID
- now `user` is assigned all of these values, one by one
- and `groups $user` takes each of these values and displays the username and all groups that account belongs to.

  ```
  guest-ZlneMD : guest-ZlneMD
  ```